# PHP Passing variables between two files

Tags: php, variables, include

I have a piece of code:

```
foreach (glob('mov/$context.mov') as $filename){ 
    $theData = file_get_contents($filename) or die("Unable to retrieve file data");
}
```

Is that the correct way to add a variable within that glob? $context

Also, in my new file, I want to replace a word with $context, so would I write

```
$context = "word"; // so it adds that word to the glob function when the script is included in a different file.
```

Comment: Use double-quotes instead of single-quotes if you to use the variable value inside the `glob`.

Comment: @bwoebi: `Is that the correct way to add a variable within that glob? $context` -- you missed this part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the double-quotes in the first parameter of the `glob` function.

```
glob("mov/$context.mov")
```

or, if you want, use brackets

```
glob("mov/{$context}.mov")
```

In this way the variable name will be replaced with the value.

**EDIT:**
For the other question:

the script with the `glob` function can be executed multiple times changing the value of the `$context` variable before the script inclusion.
Example:

```
$context = "word";
include("test.php");

$context = "foo";
include("test.php");
```

Comment: how would I replace the value between files. If I include this script in a separate php file? I want to replace $context with a word, but have $context="word"; in the file that has the script included in it.

Comment: Just change the value of the variable `$context`? It's not clear what you're trying to achieve... what's the problem when you execute your script?

Comment: Sorry, let me try to explain it a little better. The php script that uses 'foreach' is labeled test.php - I want to include that file in another php script labeled movies.php

in movies.php I'd like to just say $context ="word"; so it will replace the variable $context in test.php and work as planned. Basically, having one main script I can edit, that is included in several scripts each replacing $context with a different word so the filename can run on whatever file it's named. @Matteo

Comment: Ok, but where's the problem? You are doing something like this, right? `$context = 'word'; include('test.php');`. Then you can change `$context` every time you include a script that requires the variable.

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you for your help @Matteo you definitely pointed me in the right direction. I had forgotten to put the variable before the include on my separate php file. It's working perfectly now.

Comment: :) I edited the answer with the new part, you should choose the answer as the best.

Answer (score 3):

PHP variables are not interpolated inside single quotes. Use double quotes or put the variable out of quotes

```
foreach (glob("mov/$context.mov") as $filename){
```

or

```
foreach (glob('mov/'.$context.'.mov') as $filename){
```

If you do  `$context = "word";` before your foreach then glob will look for `mov/word.mov`

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: I wanted to put $context ="word"; in a different file, so when I include the file that runs the foreach (glob(... I can use that as my main file and run the for each on whatever filename I want. 

However, in my other script, when I include('test.php') // the script that has foreach (glob('mov/'.$context.'.mov') as $filename) and then call out $context ="word"; it doesn't work. Any idea on that?

Comment: That should work, can you post the relevant code of both files?

Answer (score 1):

You can use either of the following ways-

1.`glob("mov/$context.mov")`

2.`glob("mov/".$context.".mov")`

**Note**: ***Unlike the double-quoted syntax, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.***

For reference: **[Read More Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)**

Comment: And please tell me how's this different from the two other answers posted here?

Comment: my anwer has a supporting link.

Comment: I didn't mean to offend you, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19228324/1438393) answer also links to the documentation. +1 anyway.